# Original error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir

Tags: android, sdk, appium

I am new to **appium** and trying to make it work. The issue is when I run **appium**
it displays below given error:

> Original error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\SuperComputer\android-sdks\tools;C:\Users\SuperComputer\android-sdks\platform-tools;\build-tools

I am also attaching a log here :

```
[info] [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.7.2[info] [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"Chrome","deviceName":"android","platformName":"Android"},"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"Chrome","deviceName":"android","platformName":"Android"},"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"Chrome","platformName":"android"}]}}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"browserName":"Chrome","deviceName":"android","platformName":"Android"},null,{"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"Chrome","deviceName":"android","platformName":"Android"},"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"Chrome","platformName":"android"}]}]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1517563423205 (14:53:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[info] [Appium] Merged W3C capabilities {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"Chrome",... into desiredCapabilities object {"browserName":"Chrome","deviceName":"android",...
[info] [Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver (v1.37.0) session
[info] [Appium] Capabilities:
[info] [Appium]   browserName: Chrome
[info] [Appium]   deviceName: android
[info] [Appium]   platformName: android
[info] [BaseDriver] Session created with session id: fc535adf-8a02-41c9-9b48-8b1efd243312
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Getting Java version[info] [AndroidDriver] Java version is: 1.8.0_162
[info] [AndroidDriver] We're going to run a Chrome-based session
[info] [AndroidDriver] Chrome-type package and activity are com.android.chrome and com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
[info] [ADB] Checking whether adb is present
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Called deleteSession but bootstrap wasn't active
**[error] [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\SuperComputer\android-sdks\tools;C:\Users\SuperComputer\android-sdks\platform-tools;\build-tools'**
[info] [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 1148 ms - 296
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Observe the SDK path in the error message and make sure its correct.
You might have to fix ANDROID_HOME based on what you see

Comment: I made the necessary changes in the Android_Home, but still getting the same issue.

Comment: The latest error is as given below:
[error] [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\SuperComputer\android-sdks;\build-tools'
[info] [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 459 ms - 234

Comment: My Variable is as following: ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\SuperComputer\android-sdks;C:\Users\SuperComputer\android-sdks\build-tools\27.0.3

Comment: I think it should just be C:\Users\SuperComputer\android-sdks under ANDROID_HOME. Also add the path to build-tools, tools, platform tools to Path variable if you don't have it already.

Comment: Thanks bsk, it was actually the path issue.

Answer (score 0):

I rechecked the path and corrected it accordingly and now everthing works like a magic